# Why do I get a “list index out of range” error even though I am using the size of my string?

Tags: python, list, indexing, range, out

I expect the output of the following code

```py
def unique_in_order(iterable):
    new = []
    for letter in iterable:
        new.append(letter)
    n = len(new)
    for i in range(n):
        if new[i] == new[i+1]:
            new.pop(i)
    return new

print(unique_in_order('AAAABBBCCDAABBB'))
```

to be `['A','B','C','D','A','B']`

Why do I get the `"list index out of range"` error?

Comment: so if i replace n with n - 1 still no working

Comment: could you tag this question with the language you are using?

Comment: Your problem is [related to this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6260089/8881141). tl;dr: Don't modify lists like `new` while iterating over them. You can't change motor parts of a running car (well, you can, but don't complain when you end up in hospital).

Answer (score 2):

```py
def unique_in_order(iterable):
    new = []
    for letter in iterable:
        new.append(letter)
    n = len(new)
    for i in range(n): # <-- [2]
        if new[i] == new[i+1]:
            new.pop(i) # <-- [1]
    return new
```

In line [1] you are removing elements from your list but you are still iterating over the full range (`n`= number of elements before you removed anything) [2].

You could

- check if `i` is still smaller than the length of your list,
- replace your loop with a while loop and account for the missing indizes or
- look at the snippet @Suraj Subramanian provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```py
def unique_in_order(iterable):
    ans = [iterable[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(iterable)):
        if iterable[i] != iterable[i-1]:
            ans.append(iterable[i])
    return ans
    
print(unique_in_order('AAAABBBCCDAABBB')) # prints ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
```

Answer (score 0):

A while loop can be used instead of for loop. And we could check the length of list every time we remove one element.

```
def unique_in_order(iterable):
    new = []
    for letter in iterable:
        new.append(letter)
    n = 0
    i = 0
    n = len(new)
    while i < n - 1: # iteration should be always smaller than length of list.
        if new[i] == new[i+1]:
            new.pop(i+1)
            n = len(new)
        else:
            i = i + 1
    return new

print(unique_in_order('AAAABBBCCDAABBB'))
```